# Is it possible to support Android Pre-JellyBean and Post-JellyBean Notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean, smartphone

Is it possible to do something like this?:

```
not = AndroidCheck.isJellyBeanOrLater() ? notB.build() 
                        : notB.getNotification();
```

this turn out error on `.build()` because it is a JellyBean(API16) and later method and .getNotification() is a early to JellyBean method.

```
API MinVersion=10 Version=17
```

the objective is: the android version is early to JellyBean it uses `.getNotification()` deprecated method, if not it uses the actual `.build()` method.

Can you please try to help me? =)

thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NotificationCompat.Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) from the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) to create Notifications that work on all platform levels.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the call to .build() in a seperate class. Once Android loads the class with the call to the new API on an older Android Version Phone -> you get a RuntimeError.

Check this out:

http://code.google.com/p/android-change-log/source/browse/trunk/src/sheetrock/panda/changelog/ChangeLog.java?spec=svn52&r=52

See lines 39-41, 144-145 (here is the call to the newer API), 324-341

Comment: This is only a problem with <=1.6 Android devices. Any newer versions of Android will ignore new API calls (assuming they aren't called).